# Error for PillowWriter in Python for exporting to .gif

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, python-imaging-library, gif

I am attempting to produce some sine wave animations in python which I can then export to .gif format.
I am trying to use the PillowWriter function of matplotlib to do this in Visual Studio. I keep getting this 'list index out of range' error and cannot seem to work it out. Would appreciate any ideas on what I am doing wrong. For the record, I am pretty illiterate with programming and have just decided to teach myself Python for data visualisation during isolation, so unfortunately I am quite novice with both Python, VS, etc. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation, PillowWriter
plt.style.use('seaborn-pastel')


fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-15, 15), ylim=(-6, 6))
line1, = ax.plot([], [], lw=3)
line2, = ax.plot([], [], lw=3)
line3, = ax.plot([], [], lw=6)
line4, = ax.plot([], [], lw=3)


def init():
    line1.set_data([], [])
    line2.set_data([], [])
    line3.set_data([], [])
    line4.set_data([], [])
    return line1, line2, line3, line4,

def animate(i):
    x = np.linspace(-15, 15, 4000)
    y = np.sin(0.21 * np.pi * (x - 0.23 * i))
    y2 = np.sin(0.311 * np.pi * (x - 0.19 * i)+2.1)
    y3 = np.sin(0.307 * np.pi * (x - 0.29 * i)+4.2)
    y4 = np.sin(0.3 * np.pi * (x - 0.4 * i))
    ##yz = np.sin(0.5(freq) * np.pi * (x - 0.4(speed) * i)(displacement))
    y5 = y+y2
    y6 = y3+y5+y5+y4
    y8 = y+y2+y3
    y7 = y8+y4

    #line1.set_data(x, 5)
    #line2.set_data(x, y6)
    line3.set_data(x, y6)
    #line4.set_data(x, y8)

    return line1, line2, line3, line4,


anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=2000, interval=25, blit=True)

writer = PillowWriter(fps=20) 

anim.save("sinewaves.gif", writer=writer)  

plt.show()
```

It is the second last line where attempting to save which is where the error lies.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do that:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(-10,10,100)

for n in range(7):
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.ylim(-2,2)
    plt.plot(x,np.sin(x))
    plt.savefig(str(n)+'.png')
    plt.close()
    x += 1

from PIL import Image,ImageFilter
images = []
for n in range(7):
    exec('a'+str(n)+'=Image.open("'+str(n)+'.png")')
    images.append(eval('a'+str(n)))
images[0].save('sin.gif',
               save_all=True,
               append_images=images[1:],
               duration=100,
               loop=0)
```

Output:

[image]